# What different between HTTP protocol and HTTP server?

Tags: http, web

I just know that HTTP is the protocol that make client using browser like Chrome or Safari to get resource from web server. So HTTP is the 'protocol', But I see somewhere 'HTTP server' what is mean and What is the difference between a normal server and HTTP server?

I learned about OOP and I was thought that client-server both have HTTP method like:

```
client.HTTP.request(data)
server.HTTP.send(data)
```

Is that true?

Comment: Most network protocols have servers/clients (if asymmetric) or equally entities (symmetric). HTTP is a typical one that defines communication between HTTP servers and HTTP clients (like web browsers). You might go through the relevant IETF RFC documents to learn more about the protocol definitions, which are in plain English.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP server is a machine that understands the HTTP protocol and is able to respond to HTTP requests from clients.

An HTTP server may do things like serve webpages and process incoming data.

Comment: "understands the HTTP protocol" mean that if that protocol allow requests in parallel then The machine (HTTP server) also know how to create threads to handle those requests?

Comment: @AlexNguyen a protocol only defines the behaviors. How those behaviors should be implemented (single threading or multithreading) depend on the vendors' choices.